# Displaying geojson polygon in leaflet imported with ajax

Tags: leaflet, geojson, ajax

I'm having difficulty displaying a simple polygon in leaflet. I'm unsure if my syntax is bad or if I'm importing the geojson incorrectly. I'm using the ajax plugin from calvinmetcalf and add the js script in the head

```
<script src="leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>
```

In the body I'm adding a base layer, specifying the polygon style, and then adding the polygon as the variable 'outline'

```
<body>
<div id='map'></div><script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([45.4,-112.02], 7);

// add tile base layer
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=......', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.light'
}).addTo(map)
;

// specify polygon style for plotting
function polystyle(feature) {
return {
    fillColor: 'blue',
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'black',  //Outline color
    fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}

// import geojson using ajax
var outline = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("poly.geojson");      

// add outline to map
L.geoJSON(outline, {
    style: polystyle
}).addTo(map);

</script>
</body>
```

My poly.geojson file looks like this -- I've checked it through geojson.io and it plots fine there.

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
"crs":{"type":"name",
    "properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},
"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":0,"properties":{"Id":0},
    "geometry":{"type":"Polygon",
    "coordinates":[
        [[-112.8438,45.3956],
        [-112.4306,45.3956],
        [-112.4306,45.1617],
        [-112.8438,45.1617],
        [-112.8438,45.3956]]]
      }}]
}
```

Comment: Code look okay, try renaming geojson file to .json or .js, server may not know what to do with a geoJSON file. Here is an example that may help using JQuery instead of the plugin as an option.https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285866/leaflet-popup-showing-information-on-the-polygon/285914?noredirect=1#comment458483_285914

Comment: http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/basic/basic_Poly.html  Working demo using JQuery.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I'll try using jquery based on your examples. Renaming didn't work.

Comment: Bill, so the demo looks great, but when I try to replicate it locally or on my google storage bucket it does not display the polygon. Are there additional local dependicies that I need to consider besides the basic html file and json file (usa.json)?

Comment: Are you using IIS or apache to server the webpages? If your using windows, see if you have c:\inetpub\wwwroot that's the localhost site for IIS. If so copy the HTML and JSON file there and you should be able to hit it as http://localhost/basic_Poly.html.  If IIS is not setup, under programs/windows components/ you should see IIS (Internet Information services) .  You need to serve the json data to the html file.  In my example the HTML file and the JSON file have to be in the same folder.

Comment: This may be my problem. I'm not running a webserver. I thought it was all client-side. I just wanted to dump the html and json files on a google cloud bucket to serve - without configuring apache or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out my problem was related to Configuring Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)on the Google Cloud bucket. I needed to add the domains that hosted my source geojson file. I used [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors) configuration documentation to update my cors info.

Comment: If this solved your issue, please accept your own answer as the solution. (Click the grey ✔ next to your answer.)